# UIAlertController conflicts with UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a strange problem, where my extension of UICollectionViewFlowLayout conflicts with a UIAlertController, and removes its button.

My app has a uicollectionviewcontroller with paging enabled, and my uicollectionviewflowlayout extension makes sure a single cell fills the whole screen

```
// Extension to make a UICollectionViewCell fill the whole screen
extension UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
  public override func prepareLayout() {
    let ratio : CGFloat = 5.6 / 8.7
    
    let cardHeight = collectionView!.frame.height * 0.7
    let cardWidth = cardHeight * ratio
    let spacing = (collectionView!.frame.height - cardHeight) / 2
    
    itemSize = CGSize(width: cardWidth, height: cardHeight)
    minimumLineSpacing = spacing*2
    sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: spacing, left: 0, bottom: spacing, right: 0)
  }
}
```

And whenever I call a UIAlertController

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Error", preferredStyle: .Alert)
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel) { (action) in })
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {}
```

I get the following message in the console

```
2016-01-01 21:04:48.924 Jeg Har Aldrig[10912:3649777] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x15f6c4e80 h=--& v=--& H:[_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x15f53d9e0(19.8253)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15f67b370 H:|-(>=12)-[UIView:0x15f53e0c0]   (Names: '|':_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x15f53d9e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15f67b3c0 UIView:0x15f53e0c0.trailing <= _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x15f53d9e0.trailing - 12>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15f67b3c0 UIView:0x15f53e0c0.trailing <= _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x15f53d9e0.trailing - 12>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-01-01 21:04:48.926 Jeg Har Aldrig[10912:3649777] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x15f6c62a0 h=--& v=--& V:[_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x15f53d9e0(30.8)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15f67bd50 V:[_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x15f53d9e0(>=44)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15f67bd50 V:[_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x15f53d9e0(>=44)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-01-01 21:04:48.927 Jeg Har Aldrig[10912:3649777] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x15f6c4e80 h=--& v=--& H:[_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x15f53d9e0(19.8253)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15f67b370 H:|-(>=12)-[UIView:0x15f53e0c0]   (Names: '|':_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x15f53d9e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15f67b3c0 UIView:0x15f53e0c0.trailing <= _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x15f53d9e0.trailing - 12>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15f67b3c0 UIView:0x15f53e0c0.trailing <= _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x15f53d9e0.trailing - 12>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-01-01 21:04:48.927 Jeg Har Aldrig[10912:3649777] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x15f6c62a0 h=--& v=--& V:[_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x15f53d9e0(30.8)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15f67bd50 V:[_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x15f53d9e0(>=44)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15f67bd50 V:[_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x15f53d9e0(>=44)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-01-01 21:04:48.938 Jeg Har Aldrig[10912:3649777] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x15f6c4e80 h=--& v=--& H:[_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x15f53d9e0(19.8253)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15f67b370 H:|-(>=12)-[UIView:0x15f53e0c0]   (Names: '|':_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x15f53d9e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15f67b3c0 UIView:0x15f53e0c0.trailing <= _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x15f53d9e0.trailing - 12>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15f67b3c0 UIView:0x15f53e0c0.trailing <= _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x15f53d9e0.trailing - 12>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-01-01 21:04:48.940 Jeg Har Aldrig[10912:3649777] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x15f6c62a0 h=--& v=--& V:[_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x15f53d9e0(30.8)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15f67bd50 V:[_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x15f53d9e0(>=44)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15f67bd50 V:[_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x15f53d9e0(>=44)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

While the button on my UIAlertControllers don't appear, see the image
[image]

Any suggestiens?

**Solution based on Mattvens answer**

Instead of making an extension I made a subclass:

```
class FullCellLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    
    let ratio : CGFloat = 5.6 / 8.7
    
    let cardHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height * 0.7
    let cardWidth = cardHeight * ratio
    let spacing = (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - cardHeight) / 2
    
    itemSize = CGSize(width: cardWidth, height: cardHeight)
    minimumLineSpacing = spacing*2
    sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: spacing, left: 0, bottom: spacing, right: 0)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Don't use an extension for this.

Extensions in Swift are global, so your extension to `UICollectionViewLayout` is affecting *all* `UICollectionViewLayout` classes.

Judging from the error you are getting, `UIAlertController` is internally using `UICollectionView` to layout buttons, and your extension is breaking that functionality.

You should use a subclass, if you really need it, but there's no reason (that I know of) you can't initialize `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, assign it to a `var` and use that.

Comment: Thanks mattsven, you were absolutely right.

I will update my questien with the solution

Comment: Indeed, it is a VERY BAD IDEA to implement an existing method in an extension. You end up replacing the existing method code with your custom code, even for instances of the class that the system creates in your app. So by implementing the `prepareLayout` method in your extension to `UIAlertController`, you are changing the behavior of every alert view controller in your app. DO NOT DO THIS!